# Prevent multiple sessions accros model in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm on `rails 6.0.3` and `devise 4.7.3`

I have 2 devise models in my rails application. `User` and `Producer`

- On `localhost:3000/users/sign_in`, I can create a session with an user.
- On `localhost:3000/producers/sign_in`, I can create a session with an producer.

I was suprised to have two parallels sesssions.

In the situtation, I have acces in the same time to a `current_user` and a `current_producer`
I want to prevent this, and if you sign in with a model, it sign out automatically with the other model.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I found.

I overwrite the user controller.

```rb
# app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super
    sign_out :producer
  end
end
```

dont forget to config `routes.rb`to use this controller:

```rb
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
  # ...
end
```

I did the same thing for producer.